# How can I convert this SQL query to a lambda expression

Tags: sql-server, lambda

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], 
       [t0].[Challan_No], 
       [t0].[Type], 
       [t0].[Measurement], 
       [t0].[Update_By], 
       [t0].[Date], 
       [t1].[Id] AS [Id2], 
       [t1].[Challan_No] AS [Challan_No2], 
       [t1].[Own_Comany], 
       [t1].[Parti_Name], 
       [t1].[Update_By] AS [Update_By2], 
       [t1].[Date] AS [Date2], 
       [t1].[IsDelete], 
       [t1].[Isgenbill], 
       [t2].[Rate] AS [Rate1]
FROM [dbo].[Challan_Total] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Challan] AS [t1] ON [t0].[Challan_No] = [t1].[Challan_No]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Rate] AS [t2] ON [t0].[Type] = [t2].[Meterial_type] 
                                AND [t1].Own_Comany = [t2].Company_Id 
                                AND [t1].Parti_Name=[t2].Parti_Id
WHERE [t0].[Challan_No] = '2014CH 10002'
```

Here is what I came up with:

```
var getch = dm.Challan_Totals.Where(m => m.Challan_No == "")
                    .Join(dm.Challans,
                    c => c.Challan_No, d => d.Challan_No,
                    (c, d) => new { c, d }).Select(b => b)
                    .Join(dm.Rates, 
                    r => r.c.Type && r.d.Own_Comany && r.d.Parti_Name ,
                    s => s.Meterial_type && s.Company_Id && s.Parti_Id,
                   (r, s) => new { r, s.Rate1 });
```

Comment: This is not a code-writing service. Do some initial research, try to make something work, and if you're having trouble, please come back and ask a more specific question.

Comment: ok, I tried this below Code in C# but not Worked please help me

Comment: It would be better if you edited your OP to include the code in the comment.

Comment: Sorry to ALL i am New for this site so ..... :(

Comment: I edited your OP to include your attempt, you can delete your answer below.

Comment: One obvious error in your code is that you are trying to join using two different anonymous types as the key types, i.e. r and s. These types have different property names. Please check my edited answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will give you what you want:

```
var result = from t0 in ChallanTotal
             join t1 in Challan on t0.Challan_No equals t1.Challan_No
             join t2 in Rate on new { COL1 = t0.Type, COL2 = t1.Own_Comany, COL3 = t1.Parti_Name }
                                equals
                                new { COL1 = t2.Meterial_type, COL2 = t2.Company_Id, COL3 = t2.Parti_Id }
             where t0.Challan_No == "2014CH 10002"
             select new
             {
                 Id = t0.Id,
                 Challan_no = t0.Challan_No,
                 Type = t0.Type,
                 Id2 = t1.Id,
                 Challan_No2 = t1.Challan_No,
                 Own_Company = t1.Own_Comany,
                 Rate1 = t2.Rate1   
             };
```

This is the equivalent expression using extension methods:

```
var result = ChallanTotal.Join(Challan,
                               ct => ct.Challan_No ,
                               c => c.Challan_No,
                               (ct, c) => new { ct, c })
                         .Join(Rate,
                               ctc => new 
                               { 
                                  Type = ctc.ct.Type, 
                                  Own_Company = ctc.c.Own_Comany, 
                                  Parti_Name = ctc.c.Parti_Name 
                               },
                               rt => new 
                               { 
                                  Type = rt.Meterial_type, 
                                  Own_Company = rt.Company_Id, 
                                  Parti_Name = rt.Parti_Id 
                               },
                               (ctc, rt) => new {ctc, rt})
                         .Where(x => x.ctc.ct.Challan_No == "2014CH 10002")
                         .Select(res => new { Id = res.ctc.ct.Id,
                                              Challan_no = res.ctc.ct.Challan_No,
                                              Type = res.ctc.ct.Type,
                                              Id2 = res.ctc.c.Id,
                                              Challan_No2 = res.ctc.c.Challan_No,
                                              Own_Company = res.ctc.c.Own_Comany,
                                              Rate1 = res.rt.Rate1   
                                            });
```

The key points when joining on multiple columns are:

1. The column *types* must be the same, and
2. The column *names* must also be the same.

P.S. I have not included all of the columns being selected in the above code, but can easily add them yourself.

**EDIT:**

The above query has been tested and works OK with the following mock-up:

Class mock-up resembling the SQL Schema:

```
class Challan_Total
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Challan_No {get; set;}
    public string Type {get; set;}
}

class Challan
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Challan_No {get; set;}
    public string Own_Comany {get; set;}
    public string Parti_Name {get; set;}
}

class Rate
{
    public string Company_Id {get; set;}
    public string Parti_Id {get; set;}
    public string Meterial_type { get; set;}
    public string Rate1 { get; set; }
}
```

Sample data:

```
List<Challan_Total> lstChallanTotal = new List<Challan_Total>()
{
    new Challan_Total { Challan_No = "1", Id = 1, Type = "1"},
    new Challan_Total { Challan_No = "2", Id = 1, Type = "1"},
    new Challan_Total { Challan_No = "3", Id = 2, Type = "2"}
};

List<Challan> lstChallan = new List<Challan>()
{
    new Challan { Id = 1, Challan_No = "1", Own_Comany = "1", Parti_Name = "1"},
    new Challan { Id = 2, Challan_No = "2", Own_Comany = "1", Parti_Name = "2"},
    new Challan { Id = 3, Challan_No = "3", Own_Comany = "3", Parti_Name = "3"}
};

List<Rate> lstRate = new List<Rate>() 
{ 
    new Rate { Company_Id = "1", Parti_Id = "1", Meterial_type = "1", Rate1 = "p1"},
    new Rate { Company_Id = "2", Parti_Id = "1", Meterial_type = "1", Rate1 = "p2" },
    new Rate { Company_Id = "3", Parti_Id = "2", Meterial_type = "2", Rate1 = "p3" }
};
```

Comment: I get this type Error ,  .............      Error 1 The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Queryable.Join<TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TOuter>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TInner>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TOuter,TKey>>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TInner,TKey>>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TOuter,TInner,TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. G:\$WORKS\Iqbal Silks\Iqbal Silks\Billing_Control\Genbill.xaml.cs 84 48 Iqbal Silks

Comment: I have fully tested the code posted in my answer above. It compiles and runs without any errors in Visual Studio.

Comment: @mukesh_mourya You have to carefully examine the expressions used in order to understand how to use correctly join operations in your actual set-up (of which I am not aware of).

Comment: but , why i am gating this type error

Comment: yes, I am to checked code, its worked perfectly. when i changed type of Own_Comany,Parti_Name,Company_Id,Parti_Id    (String to int for using PRIMARY KEY and FOREIGN KEY ) thin this type of error occur

Comment: @mukesh_mourya It's impossible to tell since I don't know the exact structure of your classes. Have a look at the edit I made. The classes I've included in my mock-up closely resemble the table schema of the OP. It's a bit unfair un-accepting the answer.

Comment: @mukesh_mourya I have *arbitrarily* chosen a data type for each field since there is no reference to field types in the OP. Please pay careful attention to points 1 & 2 in my answer.

Comment: Its worked Perfectly .......:)

Comment: @mukesh_mourya I am glad it did :=)